# Fit a tikz-figure to a minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, fit

I would like to position two *tikz*-images side by side using two *minipages*. The two *tikz*-files each contain the coordinates of a 3D plot.

As you can see in the MWE, there is a lot of "unused" space to the left and to the right of the first image ("fboxes").

**My goal is to maximise the size of the tikz-figures without overlapping. Any ideas or hints are welcome.**

Here, my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{document}%
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth, height=20mm]{../bilder/tikzpic1.tikz}}
$m = 1, n = 1$
\end{minipage}}
    \hfill{}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}\centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth, height=20mm]{../bilder/tikzpic2.tikz}
        $m = 3, n = 3$
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Foobar}
    \label{fig:Foobar}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth, height=20mm]{../bilder/tikzpic1.tikz}
$m = 1, n = 1$
\end{minipage}
    \hfill{}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}\centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth, height=20mm]{../bilder/tikzpic2.tikz}
        $m = 3, n = 3$
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Foobar 2}
    \label{fig:Foobar2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of MWE]

The tikz-Files start like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
%width=\textwidth,
%height=20mm,
%at={(0,0)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=50,
tick align=outside,
ymin=0,
ymax=50,
zmin=0,
zmax=1,
view={-27}{60},
axis line style={draw=none},
ticks=none,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left
]

\addplot3[%draw opacity=0.1
surf,
line width=0.01pt, shader=flat corner, draw=black, z buffer=sort, colormap={mymap}{
```

Comment: There appears to be a lot of white space in the images.  You can't detect that automatically, but you should be able to remove it in the tikzpicture.  See `\pgfresetboundingbox` (page 184 pgf manual),